# Difficulty Connecting to Online postgreSQL Structured Database to Superset

Tags: database-connection, druid, apache-superset

I am a newbie to Superset and programming. I am trying to connect to real-time database that is stored on https location to Superset. I am having difficulty understanding the steps involved in connecting to the database. Would someone be able to tell me what steps and/or the relevant code I should follow to do this as I am finding it difficult to understand how to go about it even after looking up Apache Superset installation and configuration guide?

Cheers
Orla

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far? Here is the guidelines for asking nice, complete questions so that people can help you https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

you should see the docs about Database dependencies.
url :https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#database-dependencies 
if you want to add postgresql datasource ,like this：

```html
postgresql+psycopg2://localhost:5432/postgres?password=xxxx&user=xxxxx
```